# Acceder al elemento hijo de una tabla en html con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola tengo dos problema y he estado buscando por la web pero no encuentro alguna solución tengo una tabla con un encabezado y un cuerpo que va el contenido.

1. Lo que quiero hacer es cuando le dan click al encabezado se muestra el contenido
2. y si le dan click de nuevo se oculte (el cuerpo parte oculto)

he buscado que `nextElementSibling` accede al siguiente elemento pero solo lo veo con divs y llego a entender la logica pero con la tabla en el siguiente elemento me sale "null"

nota: estoy trabajando en un entorno donde el css no es posible aplicarlo ya que no se puede acceder a la parte del `<header> ... <\header>` por lo tanto el css lo pongo "inline" dentro de las etiquetas de html

La tabla es la siguiente:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="Header" style="height:60px;background:#f23a00;color:rgb(255, 255, 255);text-indent:20px;letter-spacing: 5px;text-transform: uppercase;width:1140px;cursor:pointer"> <b> Encabezado has click para mostrar el contenido</b> </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="overflow: hidden;display:block;height:0px;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:1140px;padding:20px 0px;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac egestas mauris. Duis quis sodales risus. Sed a urna faucibus metus consequat condimentum. Vestibulum commodo dictum libero sed porttitor. Morbi pretium imperdiet turpis, mollis suscipit est gravida at.<br></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:90px;text-align:center;background:#b1b2b2;padding:5px;"><a href="#Inicio" style="color:#EFF6FA;letter-spacing: 3px;padding:2px;text-decoration:none;">SUBIR</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

El contenido del script que tengo es el siguiente:

```js
const Cabeceras = document.querySelectorAll(".Header");

    Cabeceras.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            console.log(this); // esto lo hice por que tenia una arrow function y this paso hacer windos y entonces lo pase a function ()  y me toma bien
            console.log(panel); // aqui me arroja "null"
            /*
             CONTENIDO DE IDEA.
            */
        })
    })
```

Contenido de idea:

la idea seria acceder al *"tbody"* y mostrarlo y si le dan click de nuevo ocultarlo para esto tenia la idea de agregarle una clase como "Habilitar" con `classList.toggle` pero como no tengo un archivo css o un head donde poner alguna clase "habilitar" habia pensado en hacer algo como

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".Habilitar").forEach( (el) => {
el.style.cssText = "overflow-y: auto;display:block;height:230px;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;" 
});
```

pero no funciona no funciona cuando se le da click (no se aplica el estilo) y se le agrega la clase. hice la prueba agregando una clase en el elemento que tengo la clase `Header` y le quise cambiar el color pero no funcionaba.

Entonces tengo esos 2 problemas de como mostrar y ocultar cada vez que se le da click a la cabecera de la tabla.

Nota: el problema es cuando son mas de una tabla para uno es relativamente fácil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que quieres hacer (y lo que veo en tu código), simplemente selecciona el elemento `.Header` y agrégale un evento al hacer click. Si el elemento tiene ancho `0px`, entonces lo pones a `230px`, si tiene ancho `230px`, lo pones a 0. Con eso lograrás el efecto que buscas.

```js
function changeStyle(e) {
  const element = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
  if(element.style.height === '230px') {
    element.style.height = '0';
  } else {
    element.style.height = '230px'
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.Header').forEach(element =>{
    element.addEventListener('click',changeStyle)
})
```

```html
<table>
    <thead class="Header">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"  style="height:60px;background:#f23a00;color:rgb(255, 255, 255);text-indent:20px;letter-spacing: 5px;text-transform: uppercase;width:1140px;cursor:pointer"> <b> Encabezado has click para mostrar el contenido</b> </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="Tbody" style="overflow: hidden;display:block;height:0px;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:1140px;padding:20px 0px;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac egestas mauris. Duis quis sodales risus. Sed a urna faucibus metus consequat condimentum. Vestibulum commodo dictum libero sed porttitor. Morbi pretium imperdiet turpis, mollis suscipit est gravida at.<br></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:90px;text-align:center;background:#b1b2b2;padding:5px;"><a href="#Inicio" style="color:#EFF6FA;letter-spacing: 3px;padding:2px;text-decoration:none;">SUBIR</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead class="Header">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"  style="height:60px;background:#f23a00;color:rgb(255, 255, 255);text-indent:20px;letter-spacing: 5px;text-transform: uppercase;width:1140px;cursor:pointer"> <b> Encabezado has click para mostrar el contenido</b> </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="Tbody" style="overflow: hidden;display:block;height:0px;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:1140px;padding:20px 0px;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac egestas mauris. Duis quis sodales risus. Sed a urna faucibus metus consequat condimentum. Vestibulum commodo dictum libero sed porttitor. Morbi pretium imperdiet turpis, mollis suscipit est gravida at.<br></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:90px;text-align:center;background:#b1b2b2;padding:5px;"><a href="#Inicio" style="color:#EFF6FA;letter-spacing: 3px;padding:2px;text-decoration:none;">SUBIR</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola estaba pensando en esa solución pero creo que trae problemas cuando son mas de 1 y la idea es tener varios

Comment: @Trapss ahí lo tienes para varios elementos.